# IllegalBlockSize Exception when using asymmetric encryption (Public Private Key Enc)

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, private-key, encryption-asymmetric

I have set up public and private key encryption in Java, and distributed the public keys of the two users (communication is between two users). I now want the users to exchange a symmetric key. What I am supposed to do:

1. User A generates a key.
2. User A encrypts the key with his private key and then encrypts it with B's public key.
3. User A sends the encrypted key.
4. User B receives the encrypted key.
5. User B decrypts the key with his private key and then A's public key.

My code for user A to generate the key:

```
1. KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ENCMETHOD);
2. SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
3. int keyBitSize = 128;
4. keyGenerator.init(keyBitSize, secureRandom);
5. secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
6. encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded());

// encrypt with public key of B and then my private key
7. String encryptedMessage = encodedKey;
8. encryptedMessage = ac.encryptText
               (
                        ac.encryptText(encryptedMessage, otherUserPublickey),
                        privateKey
                );
```

Line 8 throws the following error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 117 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:344)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at driver.AsymmetricCryptography.encryptText(AsymmetricCryptography.java:73) // please refer to the code section below for this method
    at driver.ClientOne.main(ClientOne.java:158) // this is line 8 in the above code
```

The method AsymmetricCryptography.encryptText(String message, PrivateKey key):

```
public String encryptText(String msg, PrivateKey key)
        throws
        UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}

// this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `User A encrypts the key with his private key and then encrypts it with B's public key...` This just doesn't really work and is probably not a sensible way to ensure authenticity of a key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please be more specific as to why this won't work? User A encrypting with his private key ensures non-repudiation and encrypting with User B's public key ensures that only B is able to read the message, if I am right.

Comment: If you want to identify/authenticate a user, that's one thing. If you want to sign data, use a signature protocol. If you want to encrypt data, use a hybrid encryption protocol. But instead you've rolled your own scheme which isn't really clear on what it's goals are and immediately crashes into the problem outlined by @David Soroko below.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are exceeding the amount of data you can encrypt with RSA (see here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44702/whats-the-limit-on-the-size-of-the-data-that-public-key-cryptos-can-handle) which essentially is the modulus size, possibly due to Base 64 encoding.